# Generate integer numbers with mean and variance

Tags: numbers, integer, mean, sample, variance

How can I sample (integer numbers) from a t-distribution in R when I want to specify the degrees of freedom (df), the mean and variance? For example, how would I sample from a t-distribution with 8 df, mean = 4, and variance = 16?